# Display single line data in columns mysql/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

Currently I have a script that displays the data which is editable and can update the database. I have tried to enter row counts and nothing seem to work. I really like the script to make 3 columns (10 rows per column), please help.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, pounds FROM price_list ORDER BY id";
$i = 0;
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
echo "<form name='prices' method='post' action='updateA.php'>"; 

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo "<body bgColor='#5F5F6B'>";
echo "<table><table border=2 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='id[$i]' value='{$rows['id']}' >"; 
echo "<td><font color='#FFFFFF'><font size='2'>DAYS {$rows['id']}: </font><font size='2'><font color='#000000'>PRICE:<input type='text' size='1' name='pounds[$i]'  value='{$rows['pounds']}' ></tr>";

++$i;
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Update Prices Band A' />"; 
echo "</form>"; 

?>
```

The above is the original code.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Never use capital letters in path/file names. May cause hard to find problems!

Comment: Thats a horrible mess. You have a <body> tag inside the while loop, should be outside. There is no start tag <tr>. Replace the <font> tags with a styled <span style="color:#fff;font-size:12px">. You have 2 start table tags <table> and only one end table tag </table>. Start by cleaning up what you have to make sense and then maybe you will be able to see the wood for the tree's

Comment: I'm not sure what it is that you want.. You want 3 columns with 30 rows per column? or 3 columns with each representing one row? You only select 2 values out of the database. Notice that you forgot a <tr>(new row) tag before the <td> (new column) tag. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: @RensGroenveld You probably shouldn't link to w3schools; [it has a history of being inaccurate](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: I"ll keep it in mind :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you're trying to do, but this code will generate a list of all the entries in the database with the ability to change them. Note that you'll have to remake your update_a.php file:

```
<style>

    body {
        background:#5F5F6B;
        color:#fff;
    }

</style>

<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, pounds FROM price_list ORDER BY id");
if (!$sql || mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
    echo "Price list is empty";
else {
    echo '<form name="prices" method="GET" action="update_a.php">'; // Change your filename!

    $i = 0;
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo 'Day '.$rows['id'].' costs ';
        echo '<input type="text" name="'.$rows['id'].'" value="'.$rows['pounds'].'"/> pounds'
        echo '<br/>'

        $i++;
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Update Prices Band A"/>'; 
    echo "</form>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all many thanks to Leonard Pauli, the code worked perfectly in displaying the data but, it wouldn't update the database using my update.php. Below is the revised code and screenshot of what I was trying to archive.

[Screenshot of single lined data displayed in 3 columns](http://s11.postimg.org/fyvqmqgir/screenshot.png)

```
<style>

body {
    background:#5F5F6B;
    color:#fff;
    width:800px;
    height:550px;
    border:2px solid #bbb;
    padding:20px;
    float:center;
}
input[type="text"] {
width: 30px;
}
.table {
    width:180px;
    margin:1px;
    border:2px solid #bbb;
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
}
.header {
    width:595px;
    margin:1px;
    border:2px solid #bbb;
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
}
</style>
<div class="header"><b>Price List for dates from <font color ="yellow"><?php echo   "$SPA"; ?> to <?php echo "$EPA"; ?></font></div>


<?php
$dataprice = $_POST['database'];
$datesrange = $_POST['id'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, pounds FROM $dataprice ORDER BY id");

echo '<form name="prices" method="POST" action="update.php">'; 

$i = 0;
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<div class="table">Day <font color="yellow">'.$rows['id'].' </font> costs ';
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='id[$i]' value='{$rows['id']}' >";
    echo "<input type='text' name='pounds[$i]' value='{$rows['pounds']}' > Pounds";
    echo '<br/></div>';

    $i++;
}

echo "<input type='hidden' name='databases' value='$dataprice'>";
echo '<center><input type="submit" value="Update Prices"/>'; 
echo '<center><font color="yellow"><br><br><br>IF UPDATING PRICE BAND D, ONLY ENTER THE VALUE OF WHICH 
PRICES YOU WANT TO INCREASE BY, <br>EXAMPLE: 7 DAYS, IF CURRENT PRICE IS 30, IF YOU WANT TO 
CHARGE 34, ONLY ENTER 4 AND LEAVE EVERYTHING ELSE SET TO 0</b></center>';
echo "</form>";


?>
```

A bit of an idiot really, completely forgot about CSS styling.